# what is the different between channelInactive and channe.closeFuture().addListener() in Netty

Tags: java, netty

```java
 public class ChannelActiveHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler {


    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("channel open");

        // add closeListener
        ctx.channel().closeFuture().addListener(future->{

            // do somthing when channel is close!
            System.out.println("channel close! state："+ctx.channel().isActive());
        });

        super.channelActive(ctx);
    }


    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {

        // do somthing when channel is close!
        System.out.println("channel inactive！");
        super.channelInactive(ctx);
    }

}
```

As above,  what is the different of `channelInactive()` and `channel.closeFuture().addListener()` in Netty. Two method would be called when then channel is close.

Can both methods achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your use-case these are no different. That said in `channelInactive(...)` you can also delay firing the event to the next handler in the pipeline. Usually if you using `channelActive` in a handler you should also just make use of the other methods if needed.